# What is the internal define of the command of DESCRIBE and how to extend?

Tags: mysql

In short, in mysql command line interface, type `desc TABLE_Julia` is something equivalent to `select COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_KEY, COLUMN_DEFAULT, EXTRA from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_SCHEMA = database() and TABLE_NAME like 'TABLE_Julia'`

I want to know where it happened about the transform which I mean from `desc` to the equivalent `select` statement in server program, because I would like to implement the command `info TABLE_Julia`, which behaviors like `select COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_KEY, COLUMN_DEFAULT, EXTRA, COLUMN_COMMENT from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_SCHEMA = database() and TABLE_NAME like 'TABLE_Julia'`, add the `COLUMN_COMMENT`, that would be very convenient to App developers.

Actually, I already changed `lex.h`, `mysqld.cc`, `sql_cmd.h`, `sql_parse.cc`, `sql_yacc.yy`, and the result is the output of `info TABLE_Julia` is just exactly the same as `desc TABLE_Julia` now, but that is not enough.

I searched `LEX`, `do_select`, `JOIN::exec`, `mysql_execute_select`, `mysql_select`, `handle_select`, `execute_sqlcom_select`, `mysql_execute_command`, `mysql_parse`, `dispatch_command`, `do_command`, `do_handle_one_connection`, `handle_one_connection`, `pfs_spawn_thread`, `start_thread`, `clone` etc.

But, unfortunately, unlucky, still no clue. anyone please kindly give me some advice, thanks.

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RandomSeed

For mysql 5.6.12, the answer is inside method of:

```
int make_columns_old_format(THD*, st_schema_table*)
```

change from:

```
int make_columns_old_format(THD *thd, ST_SCHEMA_TABLE *schema_table)
{
      int fields_arr[]= {IS_COLUMNS_COLUMN_NAME,
                         IS_COLUMNS_COLUMN_TYPE,
                         IS_COLUMNS_COLLATION_NAME,
                         IS_COLUMNS_IS_NULLABLE,
                         IS_COLUMNS_COLUMN_KEY,
                         IS_COLUMNS_COLUMN_DEFAULT,
                         IS_COLUMNS_EXTRA,
                         IS_COLUMNS_PRIVILEGES,
                         IS_COLUMNS_COLUMN_COMMENT,
                         -1};
      int *field_num= fields_arr;
      ST_FIELD_INFO *field_info;
      Name_resolution_context *context= &thd->lex->select_lex.context;
      for (; *field_num >= 0; field_num++)
      {
        field_info= &schema_table->fields_info[*field_num];
        if (!thd->lex->verbose && (*field_num == IS_COLUMNS_COLLATION_NAME ||
                                   *field_num == IS_COLUMNS_PRIVILEGES     ||
                                   *field_num == IS_COLUMNS_COLUMN_COMMENT))
          continue;
        Item_field *field= new Item_field(context,
                                          NullS, NullS, field_info->field_name);
```

to:

```
int make_columns_old_format(THD *thd, ST_SCHEMA_TABLE *schema_table)
{
      int fields_arr[]= {IS_COLUMNS_COLUMN_NAME,
                         IS_COLUMNS_COLUMN_TYPE,
                         IS_COLUMNS_COLLATION_NAME,
                         IS_COLUMNS_IS_NULLABLE,
                         IS_COLUMNS_COLUMN_KEY,
                         IS_COLUMNS_COLUMN_DEFAULT,
                         IS_COLUMNS_EXTRA,
                         IS_COLUMNS_PRIVILEGES,
                         IS_COLUMNS_COLUMN_COMMENT,
                         -1};
      int *field_num= fields_arr;
      ST_FIELD_INFO *field_info;
      Name_resolution_context *context= &thd->lex->select_lex.context;
      for (; *field_num >= 0; field_num++)
      {
        field_info= &schema_table->fields_info[*field_num];
        if (!thd->lex->verbose && (*field_num == IS_COLUMNS_COLLATION_NAME ||
                                   *field_num == IS_COLUMNS_PRIVILEGES     /*||
                                   *field_num == IS_COLUMNS_COLUMN_COMMENT*/))
          continue;
        Item_field *field= new Item_field(context,
                                          NullS, NullS, field_info->field_name);
```

change makes program to include IS_COLUMNS_COLUMN_COMMENT, that's it:

Answer (score 1):

This certainly requires digging deep into the parser code, so I would suggest getting in touch with the MysQL devs.

On the other hand, the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE the_table` might be enough for your colleagues.

On the other other hand, you could also create a stored procedure that does the job easier. Something along the line of:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE info(tablename VARCHAR(200)
BEGIN SELECT column_name, ...,  column_comment FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = tablename;
END;

-- then
CALL info('table_name');
```

Comment: Thanks, ya, we have options, severals. the problem is not just find one option, the reason is we are not occasionally to check table info, it is very frequent operation, we would not like to type two letters if something can be done with one. I think this is also the reason of desc can perform what describe does.